# Read binary file which has different datatypes

Tags: python, numpy, binary-data

Attempting to read a binary file produced in Fortran into Python, which has some integers, some reals and logicals. At the moment I read the first few numbers correctly with:

```
x = np.fromfile(filein, dtype=np.int32, count=-1)
firstint= x[1]
...
```

(np is numpy). 
But the next item is a logical. And later on ints again and after reals. How can I do it?

Comment: May be it is much clearer if you could post a few lines from the Fortran file and why are you using the numpy ?

Comment: well the way the file is printed is very complex, long and tedious so would prefer avoid getting into it. Using numpy because I was familiar with fromfile but other suggestions are welcome

Comment: But what are you achieving from reading the binary file? what do you want to do

Comment: it contains some matrices of double precision reals, and the first few items are information on size etc which are in integer format and logical.

Comment: There is no way to read a binary file without knowing the format. The whole point of binary is that "10001011" could be a sequence of True/False values, a character, an unsigned int, etc; but there's no way to know because all the file contains are the bits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typically, when you're reading in values such as this, they're in a regular pattern (e.g. an array of C-like structs).

Another common case is a short header of various values followed by a bunch of homogenously typed data.

Let's deal with the first case first.

### Reading in Regular Patterns of Data Types

For example, you might have something like:

```
float, float, int, int, bool, float, float, int, int, bool, ...
```

If that's the case, you can define the a dtype to match the pattern of types.  In the case above, it might look like:

```
dtype=[('a', float), ('b', float), ('c', int), ('d', int), ('e', bool)]
```

(Note: there are *many* different ways to define the dtype. For example, you could also write that as `np.dtype('f8,f8,i8,i8,?')`. See the documentation for [`numpy.dtype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) for more information.)

When you read your array in, it will be a structured array with named fields.  You can later split it up into individual arrays if you'd prefer. (e.g. `series1 = data['a']` with the dtype defined above)

The main advantage of this is that reading in your data from disk will be *very* fast.  Numpy will simply read everything into memory, and then interpret the memory buffer according to the pattern you specified.

The drawback is that structured arrays behave a bit differently than regular arrays.  If you're not used to them, they'll probably seem confusing at first.  The key part to remember is that *each item in the array* is one of the patterns that you specified.  For example, for what I showed above, `data[0]` might be something like `(4.3, -1.2298, 200, 456, False)`.

### Reading in a Header

Another common case is that you have a header with a know format and then a long series of regular data.  You can still use `np.fromfile` for this, but you'll need to parse the header seperately.

First, read in the header.  You can do this in several different ways (e.g. have a look at the `struct` module in addition to `np.fromfile`, though either will probably work well for your purposes).

After that, when you pass the file object to `fromfile`, the file's internal position (i.e. the position controlled by `f.seek`) will be at the end of the header and start of the data.  If all of the rest of the file is a homogenously-typed array, a single call to `np.fromfile(f, dtype)` is all you need.

As a quick example, you might have something like the following:

```
import numpy as np

# Let's say we have a file with a 512 byte header, the 
# first 16 bytes of which are the width and height 
# stored as big-endian 64-bit integers.  The rest of the
# "main" data array is stored as little-endian 32-bit floats

with open('data.dat', 'r') as f:
    width, height = np.fromfile(f, dtype='>i8', count=2)
    # Seek to the end of the header and ignore the rest of it
    f.seek(512)
    data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float32)

# Presumably we'd want to reshape the data into a 2D array:
data = data.reshape((height, width))
```

Comment: Do you mean `infile.seek` rather than `f.seek`?

Comment: @excaza I think all those `f`'s should be `infile` instead.

Comment: Yes, those were typos on my part. I'll fix it shortly (or feel free to edit it, as well).